# Quebra de linha dentro da célula de uma tabela

Tags: html, css, table

Tenho uma tabela comum em meu HTML, porém quando uma `<td>` tem um conteúdo grande a quebra de linha não acontece, mesmo adicionando CSS:

```
table td, th {
   padding: 5px;
   white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem um word-wrap e um white-space no seu código, sendo que o white-space nowrap que vem depois não deixa o texto quebrar, com isso seu texto não quebra tire ele é o text-overflow

Comment: Entendi. Consegui o que queria, usei uma div dentro de um td, mas o problema todo estava em uma biblioteca que estou usando para converter HTML para PDF :/

Comment: @GabrielBitti entendi, acho que é essa API desse conversor de HTML pra PDF. Bom aproveito para te dar uma dica... Se a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma considere marca-la como Aceita, nesse ícone **`✔`** abaixo das setinhas no lado esquerdo da resposta que vc  achar que ajudou a resolver o problema. Assim o site não fica com a sua pergunta em aberto pendente sem resposta aceita mesmo já tendo sido resolvida. []´s

Answer (score 0):

Já tive um problema com quebra de linhas e consegui resolver com este apenas este estilo abaixo:

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```